# Impala SQL finding latest change in column from 0 to 1

Tags: sql, impala

I have a table with ID, DATE and INDICATOR. I want to find out the latest transaction where indicator value was changed from 0 to 1. The data is not sorted but for better understanding I sorted the data
as below.

```
create table my_table (id integer, date date, ind integer);

insert into my_table values 
(1, '2022-07-08', 0),
(1, '2022-08-01', 1),
(1, '2022-08-15', 1),
(1, '2022-12-01', 0),
(1, '2023-02-18', 0),
(1, '2023-05-01', 1),
(1, '2023-06-15', 0),
(1, '2023-07-01', 1);
 
SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

```
1|2022-07-08|0
1|2022-08-01|1
1|2022-08-15|1
1|2022-12-01|0
1|2023-02-18|0
1|2023-05-01|1
1|2023-06-15|0
1|2023-07-01|1
```

The answer should be the last transaction where IND changed from 0 to 1.

```
1|2023-07-01|1
```

Comment: in mysql you do this with `select * from my_table where indicator = 1 order by date desc limit 1`    ...as long as there is at least 1 row in the table where the transition happened.  If the table has 3+ rows then either (1,0,1) or (0,1,0) so that should be true.  If there are <3 rows you need additional tests.

Comment: This will not work brother. Thank you though :) @DaveS

Comment: Ah, I missed that you could insert "1" twice in a row, I thought you were only storing transitions to/from 0/1

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution. Let me know if there is any efficient way.

```
SELECT id, MAX(date) AS latest_transaction_date
FROM (
         SELECT id, date, ind,
                LAG(ind) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) AS prev_ind
         FROM my_table
     ) AS subquery
WHERE ind = 1
AND (prev_ind = 0 OR prev_ind IS NULL)
GROUP BY id;
```